# cmake CheckSymbolExists for intrinsic

Tags: cmake, intel, intrinsics

I'd like to check for intel intrinsics such as `_mm_popcnt_u32` or `_mm_blendv_epi8` using cmake. However the function `check_symbol_exists` doesn't work properly depending on the compiler. (it works with Clang but not with GCC). Indeed it is documented

> If the header files declare the symbol as a function or variable then the symbol must also be available for linking (so intrinsics may not be detected).

Is there a simple way to check for those ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the CMake documentation also states:

> If the symbol is a type, enum value, or intrinsic it will not be
>   recognized (consider using `CheckTypeSize` or `CheckCSourceCompiles`).

So, try to compile a small example with the Intel intrinsic using [`CheckCSourceCompiles`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCSourceCompiles.html#module:CheckCSourceCompiles). E.g.:

```
include(CheckCSourceCompiles)
check_c_source_compiles("
    int main() {
      int tmp = _mm_popcnt_u32(0);
      return 0;
    }
  "
  HAVE_INTRINISC
)
```